# writing on serial port through PHP class

Tags: php, serial-port

I'm writing a litte software that need to communicate to a cash drawer peripheral...

I can connect with this class

https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial

But I need to communicate in ASCII sequence, then I can't send classic "hello message"...

For example, to execute the hello message I need to write

```
(DC1) = hex 11
```

on serial communication...

How can I do that?